# How to add days, month and year to the selected date in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner

**Cypress** moment not working. Any other solution to add the days, month and year to the current or selected date.

```js
import * as moment from 'moment'

class TicketPage{
   constructor(){}
    visit(){
        cy.visit('');
    }
    clickDate(){
        const field =cy.get('#content > section.container > div > div > div.col-lg-5.mb-4.mb-lg-0 > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > input')
        field.click()
        const targetDate = Cypress.moment()
         .add(1, 'year')
         .add(1, 'month')
         .add(1, 'day')
         .format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        field.type(targetDate);
        field.invoke('attr', 'placeholder').should('contain', 'Select Date')
        return this
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress recommends [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/add#docsNav) as a replacement for moment.

The syntax looks pretty much the same:

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const targetDate = dayjs()
  .add(1, 'year')
  .add(1, 'month')
  .add(1, 'day')
  .format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```